# Spring Boot application cannot connect to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I am unable to connect my Spring Boot application to Cloud MySQL. I deploy my application in App Engine and websites that do not connect to Cloud SQL work fine. Anytime my application tries to connect to the cloud, however, I get an error. I have followed the guides for both a flexible and standard environment of https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-sql?hl=it but it doesn't seem to work. I tried following pet clinic tutorial and it didn't work. I put the following dependences in the file pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.42</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have the following items in my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/DATABASENAME?cloudSqlInstance=PROJECTID:REGION:INSTANCE&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
spring.datasource.username=USER
spring.datasource.password=*********
```

The error that I get when I try to open up the website that tries to connect to the database is:
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

What do I need to do to connect to Google Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use user and password on the same property

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/DATABASE?cloudSqlInstance=INTANCE_NAME&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=USERNAME_HERE&password=PASSWORD_HERE

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME_HERE
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD_HERE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

then make sure you have these dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.5</version>
     </dependency>
```

Remember enable google cloud sql api for your project

this works for me with standard environment. 
i used the next instructions  to make my project compatible with standard
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard

I haven't tested on flexible
good luck¡